# Layouts folder override (Read More)

Tags: template-override

Is there a way to override files form the layouts/joomla directory?
I need to change the look of the Read More button. Found its php in layouts/joomla/content/readmore.php.
Could I copy this file to my template folder and change it?

Comment: Let me guess you wanted to get rid of that chevron? Ha ha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can override the layouts by copying the file to `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/layouts/` using the same path as where you found the file.

So in your case, copy the file currently at `layouts/joomla/content/readmore.php` to `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/content/readmore.php`.